# Code throwing syntax errors for no apparent reason

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

My code currently looks like this :

```
def teams_and_games(list, player, idx):
    teams = []
    player_values = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for rows in list:
        if player == list[x][BD.player_id] and list[x][BD.player_id] not in teams:
            teams.append(list[x][BD.team])
            player_values.append([list[x][idx]]
            x += 1                
        elif player == list[x][BD.player] and list[x][BD.player_id] in teams:
            player_values[y].append(list[x][idx])
            y += 1
    return player_values, teams
```

Some of this code may be incorrect or not properly formatted - I'm still working on it. However, when it is run, it throws a syntax error on the `x += 1` statement, saying that it is invalid syntax, despite identical statements being used in the code above it without an issue. If I remove that statement, it throws another syntax error on the `elif` part of the next line - not the logical statement, or any other part of it. I can't figure out why this is happening, as the parts that create errors seem to be formatted perfectly fine.

Edit -- I'm a blind idiot. Thank you!

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket `)` on the line before `x += 1`, so Python thinks you are still writing the argument for the `append` method. Also, it's not a syntax error, but `[list[x][idx]]` is probably supposed to be `list[x][idx]` instead, based on how you're using the `player_values` list elsewhere.

Comment: In general it's a good rule of thumb that when you get a syntax error, start counting brackets in the previous line (unless there's an other more obvious reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

culprit: `teams.append(list[x][BD.team]` -- missing parenthesis

```
def teams_and_games(list, player, idx):
    teams = []
    player_values = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for rows in list:
        if player == list[x][BD.player_id] and list[x][BD.player_id] not in teams:
            teams.append(list[x][BD.team])
            player_values.append([list[x][idx]])
            x += 1                
        elif player == list[x][BD.player] and list[x][BD.player_id] in teams:
            player_values[y].append(list[x][idx])
            y += 1
    return player_values, teams
```